# iPad 3.2 & [MPMoviePlayerController setFullScreen:] not showing up

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an universal application that plays movies from the internet.  It has to support 3.1.x as well as 4.x.

In order to get this to work, I have a branch in the code that detects pre-3.2 devices and utilizes `MPMoviePlayerController` as it is supposed to work there.

This is how I prepare the player to play the remote movie:

```
- (void)registerForMovieNotifications {
    //for 3.2 devices and above
    if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(loadState)]) {
        LOG(@"moviePlayer responds to loadState, this is a 3.2+ device");

        //register the notification that the movie is ready to play
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:)
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                                   object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(didExitFullScreen:) 
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification
                                                   object:nil];

        LOG(@"preparing moviePlayer...");
        [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];



       } else {
            //for pre-3.2 devices
            LOG(@"This is a 3.1.x device");

            //register the notification that the movie is ready to play
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                     selector:@selector(moviePreloadDidFinish:)
                                                         name:MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification
                                                       object:nil];
        }

        //handle when the movie finished
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                   object:nil];
    }
    - (void)readyPlayer {
        if (!moviePlayer) {
            moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
        } else {
            [moviePlayer setContentURL:movieURL];
        }

        [self registerForMovieNotifications];
    }
```

Later on I get this notification, and it sets up the movie player's view, etc.

```
- (void) moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification {
    LOG(@"3.2/4.x - moviePlayerLoadStateChanged:");
    //unless state is unknown, start playback
    if ([moviePlayer loadState] != MPMovieLoadStateUnknown) {
        //remove observer
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                        name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                                      object:nil];

        //set the frame of the movie player to match
        self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

        [[moviePlayer view] setFrame:self.view.bounds];
        [[moviePlayer view] setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
        [[moviePlayer view] setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

        //add movie player as a subview
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
        [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES];

        //play the movie
        [moviePlayer play];

    }
}
```

And the movie plays.  This works perfectly on iPhone 4.2, 4.3, iPad 4.2, 4.3, but it fails on iPad 3.2.  The movie plays but all I get is a black screen.

If I remove the `[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES]` call I get a visible playing movie in 3.2, however it isn't "fullscreen" and so it doesn't have the Done button and there's no way for me to dismiss the screen.

I'd **love** some help on what's going on here.  Thanks!

Comment: Wish I had a device running 3.2 to test this for you. It does look like it might be a bug in 3.2. Did you try calling `setFullscreen:animated:` instead, just in case?

Comment: Remove all the view-handling from the notification handler. Leaving just the moviePlayer play method in place. Do that view-specific stuff earlier on. hth

Comment: @Nathan - yeah I did try that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to come to an acceptable solution, but I still feel this might be a bug.

If I skip the call to `setFullScreen` and instead just manually set the `controlStyle` to `MPMovieControlStyleFullScreen` then it gives me a view that is mostly correct (the toolbar is about 40 pixels too low).

Then I can get the Done button, which triggers the `moviePlayer:didFinishPlaying` callback.

So it stinks I now have a smelly `if 3.2` branch of logic in my code, but hopefully most people will be on 4.0 anyway.